# Node http-proxy: forward traffic to external https site - crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I want to transfer REST requests from my front end wepp app to the API on a external Jira server.

For this I'm using node [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy), which has been ok for a Jira server that is http.

But now I want to create a separate server for https.

So making som changes to [this](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/blob/master/examples/http/proxy-https-to-https.js) example I now have this:

```
var path  = require('path'),
    fs    = require('fs'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    certFolder = '/my/cert/folder';

//
// Create the HTTPS proxy server listening on port 8002
//
httpProxy.createServer({

  //(placeholder address)
  target: {
    host: 'https://ext.jiraserver.com',
    port: 443
  },

  // letsencrypt cert
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certFolder, 'privkey.pem'), 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certFolder, 'fullchain.pem'), 'utf8')
  },

  secure: true
}).listen(8002);

console.log('https proxy server started  on port  8002');
```

But when I make a request to my server, https://my.domain.com:8002 it crashes the server with error message:

> .../node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:119
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://ext.jiraserver.com
>   https://ext.jiraserver.com:443
>       at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)

I can't seem to get it to work... The server is online and the address is correct, so I don't know what's wrong.

Is it my code that's wrong or what can I do to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't include the `https://` in a DNS host definition.

```
host: 'ext.jiraserver.com',
```

The error message tells you that it's a DNS resolve problem. You're trying to lookup the DNS of `https://ext.jiraserver.com` including the `https`.

Comment: I tried that, and I only get: 400 Bad Request - The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port. It allmost feels like httpProxy has started a http-server, not https?

Comment: @mottosson Try adding `https: true` to the `target` config.